# Java Subclasses have a repetative method

Tags: java, inheritance, subclass

I feel like I should move the `computeResults()` methods from the subclasses to the parent, since they are identical, but when I do Eclipse warns on the Parent that `The method computeField3() and computeField4() are undefined for the type Parent` Perhaps I don't fully understand inheritance.
I can get the classes to compile as I have it below, but then are my subclasses not following the Don't Repeat Yourself principal?  Or are my classes defined properly?

```
public class Parent {
   private BigDecimal field1;
   private BigDecimal field2;
   protected BigDecimal field3;
   protected BigDecimal field4;

   protected void computeField1() {
     // math equation identical b/n all subclasses
     setField1(value);
   }
   protected void computeField2() {
     // math equation identical b/n all subclasses
     setField2(value);
   }
}

public class Child1 extends Parent {
    void computeResults() {
      // This method is redundant and I would like to move to Parent
      computeField1(); 
      computeField2(); 
      computeField3(); 
      computeField4(); 
    }


   private void computeField3() {
     // math equation for Child1 and Child2 differs for field3 
     setField3(value);
   }
   private void computeField4() {
     // math equation for Child1 and Child2 differs for field4 
     setField4(value);
   }
}

public class Child2 extends Parent {
    void computeResults() {
      // This method is redundant and I would like to move to Parent
      computeField1(); 
      computeField2(); 
      computeField3(); 
      computeField4(); 
    }

   private void computeField3() {
     // math equation for Child1 and Child2 differs for field3 
     setField3(value);
   }
   private void computeField4() {
     // math equation for Child1 and Child2 differs for field4 
     setField4(value);
   }
}
```

Comment: Mmmh, `private void computeField4 {` syntax in strange... You should use `private void computeField4() {` otherwise, your program won't be syntaxically correct. I think functions should always have parens to indicate parameters (even if there isn't any parameter).

Comment: @AlexisClarembeau , that was a typo translating real code into the question

Comment: but do you call `computeField3` and `computeField4` on a parent object or only on child object - if in your code you have something like `Parent p = new Parent(); p.computeField3()` then you need to declare computeField3 in Parent class, declare it abstract if you dont need it at this level

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that when you move `computeResults` to the parent, making its code look like

```
public class Parent {
   private BigDecimal field1;
   private BigDecimal field2;
   protected BigDecimal field3;
   protected BigDecimal field4;

   void computeResults() {
     computeField1(); 
     computeField2(); 
     computeField3(); 
     computeField4(); 
   }
   protected void computeField1() {
     // math equation identical b/n all subclasses
     setField1(value);
   }
   protected void computeField2() {
     // math equation identical b/n all subclasses
     setField2(value);
   }
}
```

it tries to call `computeField3`/`4` but doesn't find them, **because they don't exist in your code for class `Parent`**.

So you need to add `computeField3`/`4` to the `Parent` class, that the subclasses can override as they wish.

Comment: As a note, the standard way to do this is to make them abstract so that no implementation is provided in the parent class, but they must be implemented in derived classes.